# Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[REQUIRED] Environment info

- firebase-tools: 12.1.0
- "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
- "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
- "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"

**Platform: Windows wsl (Ubuntu)

- Node: v18.16.0
- Python: v3.10.6
- openjdk: v"11.0.19"

i have followed the exact steps in

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd&hl=ko#about_this_tutorial

but it occurs

"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification "

when i run "firebase  emulators:start" command

**[Error Report]**

When I run 'firebase emulators:start'

```
`i emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
```

⚠ functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, database, hosting, pubsub, storage

i firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log

✔ firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.

i ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log

i functions: Watching "/mnt/c/Users/sunwu/Downloads/Tryagain/pythontry/functions" for Cloud Functions...

✔ functions: Using node@18 from host.

**⬢ functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine
backend specification**

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔ All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/
│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator │ Host:Port │ View in Emulator UI
│
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400

Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150

***in --debug***

[2023-05-24T00:10:58.203Z] Building nodejs source

[2023-05-24T00:10:58.204Z] Failed to find version of module node: reached end of search path

/mnt/c/Users/sunwu/Downloads/Tryagain/pythontry/functions/node_modules

✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.

[2023-05-24T00:10:58.215Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery

[2023-05-24T00:10:58.240Z] Found firebase-functions binary at

'/mnt/c/Users/sunwu/Downloads/Tryagain/pythontry/functions/node_modules/.bin/firebase-functions'

[2023-05-24T00:11:02.712Z] Serving at port 8528

[2023-05-24T00:11:16.857Z] shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit

⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification"}}

it is just a simple project so i have  no idea why its not working..

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error

Error: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification.

Turns out that when I initialized a new project using **firebase init** the default **nodejs** version it uses is **18**.

Just needed to change my version in **package.json** file to the current installed on my system. For me it was **16**.

**"engines": {
"node": "16"
},**

#### Error Image

[image: Error Image]

#### Success Image

[image: Success Image]

Comment: changed to all the versions that i know but still not working..

Comment: @sunwu can you paste your package.json file content and command prompt screenshot showing the node versions?

Feel free to reach out to me via email at syedhamzahoda@gmail.com Would love to help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Worked for me - set engines in package.json to the same version I'd set in the "functions" object in firebase.json for my next,js/firebase project

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error when trying to "deploy" an onCall function, I got the error and when I executed `firebase emulators:start` I also got the same error.

I researched for several hours but none of the options they gave me worked, from downloading my versions of firebase, node and npm, to modifying lines of code in the firebase-tools project, there was something that worked for me

version information:

`SO:Kali_Linux 2023.3`

`Node: 16.16/18.18`

`npm: 10.2.0`

`firebase: 12.6.2 (installation media CLI: "sudo npm install -g firebase-tool")`

Open the file with the following path (you will need root permissions) and edit the following variable:

`path - /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/runtimes/discovery/index.js`

too

`path - project_firebase_tools/src/deploy/functions/runtimes/discovery /index.ts`

Edit param `timeout` in function `detectFromPort`

`Before ->  timeout = 10000 After -> timeout = 50000`

Make sure you save changes correctly and do your `firebase deploy/firebase emulators:start` without the annoying error.

PD: I'm not sure what's going on with this, in case this could be a strong solution for everyone I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: same problem here with CentOS 9 Stream: firebase-tools version 13.0.2 / node 18. This made it works

Comment: No idea what's going on but this helped on macOS too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To help everyone on this; I am using firebase-tools v13.5.1.

I was getting the unhelpful error:

```
[error] !!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to parse build specification {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to parse build specification"}}
[info]
```

It turns out there isn't enough debug logging... The problem is the throw turns the child error into "[object]". So we need to debug log the ACTUAL error object to see the detail...

1. I installed the package locally; `npm i --save-dev firebase-tools`
2. I edited functions\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\runtimes\discovery\index.js
   2.1 In the catch (Line 25) I added a debug print with the err

```
catch (err) {
        logger_1.logger.debug("Failed to parse build specification", err);
        throw new error_1.FirebaseError("Failed to parse build specification", { children: [err] });
    }
```

Running firebase:start with --debug (ie:  `npm run serve -- --debug`) now shows a more detailed error in the logs:

```
[debug] [2024-03-19T08:24:18.159Z] Failed to parse build specification string endpoints[addproduct].ingressSettings failed validation {"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"exit":1,"message":"string endpoints[addproduct].ingressSettings failed validation","status":500}
```

So I corrected my "ingressSettings" and it all worked!